# Show Control from ViewModel in UI

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl in my ViewModel which needs to be changed depending on context of my ViewModel.

For example: my ViewModel contains an enum. When the value of this enum is `Test1`, the CurrentView property will be changed to an object of type `MyCustomTest1`. When the value is `Test2`, the property becomes an object of `MyCustomTest2`. I already know how to implement this but can't figure out how I can tell my UI to render the CustomControl.

I think I'll need to use ItemsControl for this but I'm not sure about this. This is what I've tried so far.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="MainContent" Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentView, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

My Custom component simply contains a StackPanel with a TextBlock.

MyCustomTest1:

```
<StackPanel>
   <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

My ViewModel calls INotifyPropertyChanged when the CurrentView has been updated.

```
public UserControl CurrentView 
        { 
            get => currentView;
            private set
            {
                currentView = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CurrentView)));
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know how to achive this?

Comment: `<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>` would work. However, having a UserControl in a view model seems odd. Better declare the UserControl in a DataTemplate that is applied to a ContentControl or ContentPresenter when an associated data item is used as Content. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view model must never know any controls. Controls are only handled in the view.

Your problem is usually solved by making use of data models and an associated `DataTemplated`, which instructs the view on how to render the data model.

This means you should introduce a data model for each view. Then bind this model to a `ContentControl`. The `ContentControl` will then apply the `DataTemplate` for the data type of the model and the view will get rendered.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // TODO::Let this property raise the PropertyChanged event
  public object CurrentViewModel { get; set; }

  private void LoadView()
  {
    this.CurrentView = new MyCustomControlViewModel();
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.Resources>

  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyCustomControlViewModel}">
      <MyCustomControl />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
</Window>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can design a ValueConverter, like:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

public class MyValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is ControlType type)
        {
            if (type == ControlType.Type1)
                return new MyCustomTest1();
            else if (type == ControlType.Type2)
                return new MyCustomTest2();
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can add a `ContentControl`, and bind its `Content` to the enum property, and introduce the Converter:

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- vc is the namespace where you put the value converter class -->
    <vc:MyValueConverter x:Key="converter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
```

Comment: This is so not MVVM. There is never a reason to have UI controls referenced in the ViewModel.